# Weird behavior of defmacro and intern - symbolp error

Tags: elisp-macros

I have the following macro

```
(defmacro test-macro (arg)
  `(defun (intern (concat "test-func-called" ,arg)) ()
     (message "I do nothing")))
```

When I call to this macro

```
(test-macro "test")
```

It gives me the following error

```
Wrong type argument: symbolp, (intern (concat "test-func-called" "test"))
```

Evaluating the following gives me `t`

```
(symbolp (intern (concat "test-func-called" "test")))
```

Comment: You need to unquote the intern. Put a comma before its opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you test macros is with [`macroexpand`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html):

```
(macroexpand-1 '(test-macro "test"))
==> (defun (intern (concat "test-func-called" "test")) nil (message "I do nothing"))
```

This makes the error obvious: the function `intern` should be called at
macroexpansion time, not at evaluation time (since `defun` does not
evaluate its first argument).

Thus, the fix is:

```
(defmacro test-macro (arg)
  `(defun ,(intern (concat "test-func-called" arg)) ()
     (message "I do nothing")))
(macroexpand-1 '(test-macro "test"))
==> (defun test-func-calledtest nil (message "I do nothing"))
```

Comment: Or use `macroexpand` if before Emacs 25, where `macroexpand-1` is introduced. That returns `(defalias (quote (intern (concat "test-func-called" "test")))
  (function (lambda nil (message "I do nothing"))))`, which indicates the same problem, but expressed in terms of `defalias`, not `defun`.

Comment: Thanks! On a separate note, is that a good way to define a macro that defines a function? Basically I want to define 5-6 interactive functions by writing one macro and then call it to create functions for me.

Comment: @RussKiselev: yes, this is the way to go; try macroexpanding `defstruct` forms.